# “Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...” message show in the screen for a long time!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, devkit

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>gem install passenger

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

After I had installed the DevKit ( http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit), I must wait for a long time when I install passenger , (now...It has past 20 minutes) ,why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phusion Passenger doesn't support Windows.